# Iterate over list from leading and trailing with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, concurrency, multiprocessing

I want to iterate over a list with 2 function using multiprocessing one function iterate over the main_list from leading and other from trailing, I want this function each time that iterates over the sample list (`g`) put the element in main list till one of them find a duplicate in list then I want the terminate both processes and return the seen elements.

I expect that the first process return :

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

And the second return :

```
['l', 'k', 'j', 'i', 'h', 'g']
```

this is my code that returns an Error:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

manager = Manager()
d = manager.list()

# Fn definitions and such
def a(main_path,g,l=[]):
  for i in g:
    l.append(i)
    print 'a'
    if i in main_path:
      return l
    main_path.append(i)

def b(main_path,g,l=[]):
  for i in g:
    l.append(i)
    print 'b'
    if i in main_path:
      return l
    main_path.append(i)

g=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']
g2=g[::-1]

p1 = Process(target=a, args=(d,g))
p2 = Process(target=b, args=(d,g2))
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

And this is the `Traceback`:

```
a
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/bluebird/Desktop/persiantext.py", line 17, in a
    if i in main_path:
  File "<string>", line 2, in __contains__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 755, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 742, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 169, in Client
b
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 304, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/bluebird/Desktop/persiantext.py", line 27, in b
    if i in main_path:
  File "<string>", line 2, in __contains__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 755, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 742, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 169, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 304, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Note that i have not any idea that how terminate both processes after that one of them find a duplicated element!!

Comment: First, other than not blocking on a `q.join()` that can never return, this has all the same problems as your other version, except that you've made the synchronization more expensive by making it between processes instead of between threads. If you're lucky, that may actually make problems easier to easy and intermittent failures fail more often, but it's not going to fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all kinds of other problems in your code, but since I already explained them on your other question, I won't get into them here.

The new problem is that you're not `join`ing your child processes. In your threaded version, this wasn't an issue just because your main thread accidentally had a "block forever" before the end. But here, you don't have that, so the main process reaches the end of the script while the background processes are still running.

When this happens, it's not entirely defined what your code will do.<sup>*</sup> But basically, you're destroying the manager object, which shuts down the manager server while the background processes are still using it, so they're going to raise exceptions the next time they try to access a managed object.

The solution is to add `p1.join()` and `p2.join()` to the end of your script.

But that really only gets you back to the same situation as your threaded code (except not blocking forever at the end). You've still got code that's completely serialized, and a big race condition, and so on.

---

If you're curious why this happens:

At the end of the script, all of your module's globals go out of scope.<sup>**</sup> Since those variables are the only reference you have to the manager and process objects, those objects get garbage-collected, and their destructors get called.

For a manager object, the destructor shuts down the server.

For a process object, I'm not entirely sure, but I think the destructor does *nothing* (rather than join it and/or interrupt it). Instead, there's an atexit function, that runs after all of the destructors, that joins any still-running processes.<sup>***</sup>

So, first the manager goes away, then the main process starts waiting for the children to finish; the next time each one tries to access a managed object, it fails and exits. Once all of them do that, the main process finishes waiting and exits.

---

<sub>* The `multiprocessing` changes in 3.2 and the shutdown changes in 3.4 make things a lot cleaner, so if we weren't talking about 2.7, there would be less "here's what usually happens but not always" and "here's what happens in one particular implementation on one particular platform".</sub>

<sub>** This isn't actually guaranteed by 2.7, and garbage-collecting all of the modules' globals doesn't always happen. But in this particular simple case, I'm *pretty* sure it *will* always work this way, at least in CPython, although I don't want to try to explain why.</sub>

<sub>*** That's definitely how it works with threads, at least on CPython 2.7 on Unix… again, this isn't at all documented in 2.x, so you can only tell by reading the source or experimenting on the platforms/implementations/versions that matter to you… And I don't want to track this through the source unless there's likely to be something puzzling or interesting to find.</sub>