# Working of Cache-mem using Queue in Python

Tags: python, list, caching, queue

I have written code to simulate the working of cache memory.

In this model, I try to realize the FIFO-algorithm which allows us to delete the last unused element (data, value, whatever).

I wrote a special function, which gives me a list **o** with numbers (these numbers are addresses in memory).

```
q=Queue.Queue(800)# Cache - memory. This is a queue which is more likely help me to simulate FIFO-algorithm
QW=[] # External memory
l=raw_input("Enter a desire operation:")#I enter my operation.
for i in range(len(o)):
    time.sleep(0.4)
    u = time.time()
    k=o.pop(0) #o - is the list with numbers (these numbers are addresses in memory). Here I get each address through pop.
    while l=='read': #If operation is "read" then i need to get my adress from q (cache-mem) or from QW (Is the external memory) and put it in q - (is the Cache-memory).
        if k not in q:
            if j in QW and k==j:
                q.put(j)
        else:
            q.get(k)
    while l=='record':#If operation is "record" then i need to write (append to QW) an address in QW or q, but only if the same address have existed already in QW or q.
        if k not in q:
            QW.append(k)
            print QW
        else:
            q.put(k)
    print q.get()
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'instance' is not iterable at line
  if k not in q
```

Comment: Where did `Queue.Queue` come from? Is it from some 3rd party library?

Comment: Hi Alex, Correction: You can do `if k not in q.queue`but see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16506527/3727050) for issues and thread safety

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with Queues I think, instead use collections.dequeue which are almost similar while collections have fast append(), pop(). You can change your code first line to `q=collections.deque([],800)` and in place of q.put,q.get use `q.append` ,`q.popleft()`.

Comment: rakesh, thanks! But what q.popleft(). does  do?  it deletes and reads or reads only?

Comment: I tried to change my line where is the q=, but i get the mistake NameError: name 'collections' is not defined

Comment: You have to import the module first by executing the statement ``import collections``.

Comment: This function q.popleft() does 2 opperations: remove and return, although i need return only. Does someone knows about this function in queue

Comment: collections.queue isn't that i need, because it deletes the elements which have more low number, right? I would specify time of addition for every element. It needs to deleting of element in time order

Comment: You can use access dequeue like lists.If you need return only you can use q[index]. Also if you want to delete in time order then you should add it in that order. If you add using q.append(num), then you can get it using q[index] or pop it  using q.pop()