# Time Complexity of OrderedSet() in python

Tags: python, time-complexity, ordered-set

I was going through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506527/5161197) on Stack Overflow. I came to know about existence of `OrderedSet` in **Python**. I would like to know how it is implemented internally. Is it similar to hash table implementation of sets?

Also, what is the time complexity of some of the common operations like insert, delete, find, etc.?

Comment: Did you read the [linked documentation](http://orderedset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? OrderedSet isn't part of the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for the link @jonrsharpe. The [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) to the implementation was useful

Comment: @likecs then maybe you could answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation available [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/)

> Implementation based on a doubly linked link and an internal
>   dictionary. This design gives OrderedSet the same big-Oh running times
>   as regular sets including O(1) adds, removes, and lookups as well as
>   O(n) iteration.

There is also a discussion on the topic, see [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)